# create a matrix and row/col names in loop, in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I want a 7*17 matrix. 
row names are from 2:8 ( first row name to be 2, 2nd row to be 3 and ...)
colnames are 4:17 ( first column has name 4 and 2nd column has name 5 and ... ) 
matrix elements are filled such that mat[i,j] = rowname of ith row * colnames of jth col.

I get error with what I m attempting:

```
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 7, ncol = 17 , byrow = TRUE)
for (rr in 2:8) {
  row.names(mat)[rr-1] <- paste('class', rr, sep='.')
  for(cc in 4:20){
    mat[rr-1,cc-3] <- rr*cc
    colnames(mat)[cc] <- paste('count', cc, sep='.')
      }
}
```

this is the error:

> Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :
> length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array

how can I fix this.

Comment: Ought to be used a matrix or could you use a `dataframe` with one column containing names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with the code in the question:

1. It is trying to insert names into the names vectors but no names have been set on the matrix.
2. `colnames(mat)[cc]<-...` should be `colnames(mat)[cc-3]<-`
3. Using `byrow=TRUE` is not an error but it is pointless since every element is 0 so it doesn't matter what order 0 is inserted.

**1)** Suggest doing it this way instead:

```
rr <- 2:8
cc <- 4:20
mat <- outer(rr, cc)
dimnames(mat) <- list(paste0("class.", rr), paste0("count.", cc))
```

**2)** Alternately, this could be done via list comprehensions using the listcompr package.  For each value of r in rr the `gen.named.vector` call creates a named vector forming one row and then `gen.named.matrix` creates a matrix from the rows.

```
library(listcompr)
gen.named.matrix("class.{r}", gen.named.vector("count.{c}", c*r, c = cc), r = rr)
```

**3)** If you want to fix up the code in the question then do it like this:

```
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 7, ncol = 17 ,
  dimnames = list(character(7), character(17)))
for (rr in 2:8) {
  rownames(mat)[rr-1] <- paste('class', rr, sep='.')
  for(cc in 4:20) {
    mat[rr-1, cc-3] <- rr * cc
    colnames(mat)[cc-3] <- paste('count', cc, sep='.')
  }
}
```

Comment: this is great. it is just , I want the pattern of "class.2", "class.3", ... for row names and "count.4", "count.5", ... for colnames. not just the numbers.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: thanks. well I have to create my matrix from the loop I brought in the question. I m just wondering why $dimnames(mat) <- list(paste0("class.", rr), paste0("count.", cc))$ gives same error for matrix from loop but no error for matrix from outer().

Comment: The argument of dimnames should be your matrix. Create the matrix first and then assign the names.